# mongodb node js query on time zone and how can i do query using dynamic timezone

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, timezone

I have one question?
How can I do query over timezone in mongodb.

```
createdAt: {$gte: new Date(new Date() - 7 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000)}
```

Bd timezone.

Comment: What do you mean by "How can I do query over timezone"? `Date` objects in MongoDB are always UTC times, comparison is always done at UTC. If your input value is a local time, then convert it to UTC first.

Comment: Maybe use a library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/): Would be like this: `{$gte: moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").subtract(7, 'day').toDate()}`

Comment: if i want to do query in mongodb with out using any kind of library how can I do it for getting only last 7 days data in my loca timezone

Comment: That's what your condition is doing. What else do you want?

Comment: my condition is not using tz in this..
createdAt: {$gte: new Date(new Date() - 7 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000)} I want to know how to use tz in this query and do query in mongodb atlas